# Why grep \n matches every line

Tags: bash, grep

I found that `grep $'xxx\nxxx' file`, where `xxx` can be anything, prints every line of `file`. I'm a little confused about that. Does anyone get any clues? Thanks.

The grep version is "GNU grep 2.6.3"

Comment: What version of grep are you using? I haven't experienced the same you have, not even running the exact same command: `grep $'xxx\nxxx' <file>`. I'm using grep (GNU grep) 2.18,

Comment: Mine is GNU grep 2.6.3，so maybe it is a bug?

Comment: Sorry Rubens, I only tried `grep $'xxx\n' file` and `grep $'\nxxx' file` and jump to conclusion. Thanks for reply.

Comment: +1 No problem, Morris. That was indeed a nice question; and a very interesting discovery, at least for me! :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It tried this on `grep` version 2.12 and it appears to be a feature, not a bug.  Consider the file:

```
$ cat >file
Jerry
Bob
Phil 
Pigpen
```

Now, try `grep`:

```
$ grep $'J.*y\nP.il' file
Jerry
Phil
```

It appears that each line of input is treated as a separate regex pattern to match and the patterns are or'd together.

Note that an empty pattern matches everything:

```
$ grep $'J.*y\n' file
Jerry
Bob
Phil
Pigpen
```

Comment: It works exactly as you said in my `grep`. Thanks a lot.